# There always exists a multiple with the specified number of digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

> For any positive natural number $N$, with any number of digits there is a multiple of $N$ with that many digits, as long as it is at least as many as are in $N$.
>
> This is true for any base (binary, terenary, decimal, hexadecimal, etc).

For example, there is a multiple of $37$ with $7$ digits : $1,850,000 = 37 \times 50,000$.

I came across this problem writing some software. I needed it to be true to prove the correctness of an arithmetic program.

I managed to prove/disprove it, thought someone else might enjoy trying.

Comment: Did you try multiplying by $b^{k-n}$? where $b$ is the base, $k$ is the number of desired digits, and $n$ is the number of digits of $N$ (in base $b$)?

Comment: @CalvinLin I took a different approach for my solution.

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence. Did you manage to, or you didn't manage to prove or disprove it?

Comment: For $ \text{base} _ {10}$ , multiplying a number $k$ by $10^x$ will increase the digits of $k$ by $x.$

Comment: What’s the stance of this site for already solved problems? I’m fine by that, but I’m not absolutely sure everybody else would.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I did, I'm posting this b/c I think others might like to try.

Comment: @URL I agree with O.P that if even though it is a solved problem , it can be useful for somebody else .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, for a contradiction, that there are no $k$-digit multiples of an $n$-digit integer $N$, in base $b$, for $n\leq k$. Since one out of every $N$ consecutive integers must be a multiple of $N$, this implies $$b^k-b^{k-1}<N\Rightarrow$$ $$(b-1)\cdot b^{k-1}<N.$$ However, by hypothesis, $N<b^{n-1}$. This is only possible if $n=k$. But in that case, $N$ is a $k$-digit multiple of $N$, and we’ve arrived at our contradiction. $\blacksquare$